# Frida problem unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed

Tags: frida

I am using `bluestack arm32` and its rooted.
I tried it in `x86` it work but it return null after finding `libil2cpp.so` and other `libs` in all unity game using `module.findBaseAddress()`.

So i tried `arm32` and `x64` it then `frida` show this error:
`"unable to connect to remote frida-server: closed"`.

Comment: If I remember correctly all Bluestacks emulators are x86 based, the ARM32 bit is only emulated most likely the same way Android Emulator does. For those emulation layers frida often has problems. Therefore I would recommend to use a plain emulator without additional emulation layer inside.

Comment: Can you suggest some plain emulator other than android studio emulator because it does not support arm

Comment: If you need ARM + Frida my recommendation is a physical device.